# How do I get JWT working in Autorest generated SDK? (ASP.NET Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, rest, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, autorest

I want to be able to login to my identity database with user name and password and retreive a JWT.  Then I want to use the JWT to access data securely from my API.

I found out that the SDK code generated by VS2017 uses an old version of autorest, so I have switched to using [Azure Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest)

The api and the SDK are both ASP.NET Core 2.0

To generate the SDK I use

```
AutoRest -mynamespace mytrack.Client -CodeGenerator CSharp -Modeler 
Swagger -Input swagger.json -PackageName mytrack.client -AddCredentials true
```

The versions show as

```
AutoRest code generation utility [version: 2.0.4262; node: v8.11.2]
```

I have written my test as

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using swagger; // my name space from the autorest command, not to be confused with swagger itself.
using swagger.Models;

namespace CoreClientTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            try
            {
                GetMyJob().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static async Task GetMyJob()
        {
            var tokenRequest = new TokenRequest
            {
                Username = "myusername",
                Password = "mypassword"
            };

            var credentials = new TokenCredentials("bearer token");
            var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44348", UriKind.Absolute);
            var tokenClient = new Track3API(uri, credentials);
            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.ApiRequestTokenPostWithHttpMessagesAsync(tokenRequest);
            var tokenContent = await tokenResponse.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var tokenString = JObject.Parse(tokenContent).GetValue("token").ToString();
            var creds2 = new TokenCredentials(tokenString);
            var client2 = new Track3API(uri, creds2);
            var result = await client2.ApiJobsByIdGetWithHttpMessagesAsync(1);
            var response = result.Response;
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the result has OK and I can see the token in it.
I cant see the return job

The method in the api has

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/jobs")]
public class JobController : Controller
{


/// <summary>
/// Returns Job Header for Id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var header1 = new JobHeader
    {
        JobNumber = "1234",
        Id = id,
        CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber = "fred"
    };
    return Ok(header1);
}
```

}

Comment: You should apply the `DataContract` attribute over the class so that when RestClient consumes the service reference, it also generate the types. Read it here -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Are you using Web API 2? Or is it ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Add the error stack trace as well, which should help people look into the problem better

Comment: reading https://dzimchuk.net/generating-clients-for-your-apis-with-autorest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is working.
I found a tip at [Andrei Dzimchuk's blog](https://dzimchuk.net/generating-clients-for-your-apis-with-autorest/) on setting up the token

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using swagger;
using swagger.Models;

namespace CoreClientTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            try
            {
                 GetMyJob().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<JobHeader> GetMyJob()
        {
            var tokenRequest = new TokenRequest
            {
                Username = "myusername",
                Password = "mypassword"
            };
            var credentials = new TokenCredentials("bearer token");
            var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44348", UriKind.Absolute);
            var tokenClient = new Track3API(uri, credentials);
            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.ApiRequestTokenPostWithHttpMessagesAsync(tokenRequest);
            var tokenContent = await tokenResponse.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var tokenString = JObject.Parse(tokenContent).GetValue("token").ToString();
            var creds2 = new TokenCredentials(tokenString);
            var client2 = new Track3API(uri, creds2);
            var result = await client2.ApiJobsByIdGetWithHttpMessagesAsync(1);
            string resultContent = await result.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var job = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobHeader>(resultContent);
            Console.WriteLine(job.JobNumber);
            return job;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the `DataContract` attribute over the class so that when RestClient consumes the service reference, it also generate the types.

Read it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).

You should also attach `DatamMember` attribute on Property. See below example

```
[DataContract]
class Person 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int id)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

When Rest Client consume the service, it will generate the classes at client side for those classes which are attributed with `DataContract`.

Comment: I tried this but could not see any difference in the generated model ( sorry about the big re-write of the question)